# DataGridView changing cell background color

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following code :

```
private void dgvStatus_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvStatus.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[color.Index].Style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(((GesTest.dsEssais.FMstatusAnomalieRow)row.DataBoundItem).iColor);
    }
}
```

I am trying to set the background color of each cell from the background color column. this doesn't work the color never change. Any idea of why?

I've been looking around but didn't found anything usefull

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working. Here the code :

```
private void dgvStatus_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != color.Index)
        return;

    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse(((DataRowView)dgvStatus.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row[4].ToString()));
}
```

if anyone know a better to do this please don't hesitate to post it. I'm open to suggestion

Comment: I'm trying to replace `Row[4]` by `Row[color.index]` it compile but at run time i got a FormatException. color is the datagridcolumn name and it's value is 4... i dont't know why this doesn't work. Any advise?

Comment: Looks like you're using the approach outlined in the "Setting Styles Dynamically" section of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yef90x0.aspx which my previous link's answer from @EJC refers to.

Comment: In DataViews you can use column names too (strings), not just numerical indexes: e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(int.Parse( ((DataRowView)dgvStatus.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row[ **"colorColumn"** ].ToString() ));

Answer (score 39):

Simply create a new [DataGridViewCellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) object, set its back color and then assign the cell's style to it:

```
    DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
    style.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(((GesTest.dsEssais.FMstatusAnomalieRow)row.DataBoundItem).iColor);
    style.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    row.Cells[color.Index].Style = style;
```

Comment: tryed your code and it didn't helped. I gave a look at your link and it doesn't really help

Answer (score 12):

If you are still intrested in *why* this didn't work for you at first:

The reason you don't see changes you've made to the cell's style is because you do these changes *before* the form was shown, and so they are disregarded.

Changing cell styles in the events suggested here will do the job, but they are called multiple times causing your style changes to happen more times than you wish, and so aren't very efficient.

To solve this, either change the style after the point in your code in which the form is shown, or subscribe to the Shown event, and place your changes there (this is event is called significantly less than the other events suggested).

Comment: I can't find the Shown event. Can you provide a small sample on how to change color formatting by subscribing to an even that only calls once and after the datagridview is shown so that changes actually show? Thanks!

Comment: @konrad I don't know about "only called once", but I used RowsAdded lately, and it was good enough for me, as I only had a few rows, so it wasn't called too much. I haven't really played around with this control since posting this answer, so I don't know what is a good substitute for Shown

Comment: @konrad You can take a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58249741/3375713).

Comment: Awesome response @Ysch!

Answer (score 10):

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
```

Comment: int rowscount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;         

for (int i = 0; i < rowscount; i++)
{            

if (!(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value == null))
{
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
}

}

Answer (score 6):

```
int rowscount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;         

for (int i = 0; i < rowscount; i++)
{            
    if (!(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value == null))
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`VisibleChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged?view=netframework-4.8) event handler.

```
private void DataGridView1_VisibleChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as DataGridView;
    grid.Rows[0].Cells[0].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar as shown and mentioned:

**Notes:** Take into consideration that Cells will change their color **(only)** after the DataGridView Control is Visible.
Therefore one practical solution would be using the:

> VisibleChanged Event

In case you wish to keep your style when creating new Rows; also subscribe the:

> RowsAdded Event

**Example bellow:**

```
///<summary> Instantiate the DataGridView Control. </summary>
private DataGridView dgView = new DataGridView;

///<summary> Method to configure DataGridView Control. </summary>
private void DataGridView_Configuration()
{
    // In this case the method just contains the VisibleChanged event subscription.

    dgView.VisibleChanged += DgView_VisibleChanged;

    // Uncomment line bellow in case you want to keep the style when creating new rows.
    // dgView.RowsAdded += DgView_RowsAdded;
}

///<summary> The actual Method that will re-design (Paint) DataGridView Cells. </summary>
 private void DataGridView_PaintCells()
 {
     int nrRows = dgView.Rows.Count;
     int nrColumns = dgView.Columns.Count;
     Color green = Color.LimeGreen;

     // Iterate over the total number of Rows
     for (int row = 0; row < nrRows; row++)
     {
         // Iterate over the total number of Columns
         for (int col = 0; col < nrColumns; col++) 
         {
             // Paint cell location (column, row)
             dgView[col, row].Style.BackColor = green;
         }
     }
 }

///<summary> The DataGridView VisibleChanged Event. </summary>
private void DataGridView_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView_PaintCells();
}

/// <summary> Occurrs when a new Row is Created. </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void DataGridView_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{ 
    DataGridView_PaintCells(); 
}
```

**Finally:** Just call the DataGridView_Configuration() (method)

**i.e:** Form Load Event.

Answer (score 0):

try the following (in RowDataBound method of GridView):

```
protected void GridViewUsers_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    // this will only change the rows backgound not the column header 

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan; //first col
        e.Row.Cells[1].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black; // second col
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void grdDataListeDetay_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (e.Row.Cells[3].Text != "0")
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Beige;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OP's question is about DataGridView not the GridView control.

Comment: Why `i <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1`? Why not `i < e.Row.Cells.Count`

Answer (score 0):

```
dataGridView1[row, col].Style.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: and be aware that it is [col, row] - so the first index is for columns and the second one for rows

Comment: @TomPez, perhaps, btw, i don't remember it now.