# How to set the background color for specified row in datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to set the background color for specified Row in datagridview ..
My need is i have a for loop `(i=0;i<10;i++)` .Inside this for loop i write the logic 
as

```
if(i=1)
{
//Want to Set Color For This Specified Row..
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[1].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
}

if(i=1)
{
//Want to Set Color For This Specified Row..
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[2].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Blue;
}


if(i=1)
{
//Want to Set Color For This Specified Row..
dataGridView1.SelectedRows[3].DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

But i didn't get the expected o/p . I hope U understand My need . Please Help Me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2193018/815938

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `SelectedRows` property of the DataGridview you can use as follows

```
dataGridView1.Rows[1].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Because `SelectedRows` property will return rows when row(s) has been selected by the User only, if no rows are selected then your code will throw exception.

EDIT :

For your doubt here am providing a sample code, hope it will help you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
 {
   if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > i)
    {
      if (i == 1)
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
      else if (i == 2)
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
      else
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Green;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may handle different events of your datagrid and set cell style

Here is example from [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105718/datagridview-changing-cell-background-color)

```
private void dgvStatus_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex != color.Index)
        return;

    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```