# Changing elements in datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have been struggling the past few days to change the color of rows in a datagridview depending on the date displayed in one of the cells. I've looked at many examples on here but none of them have helped so far. Here's what I have right now:

```
for (int i = 0; i < eolGrid.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime dateval = Convert.ToDateTime(eolGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);

            if (dateval <= date)
                eolGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            else if (dateval <= date.AddDays(14))
                eolGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
            else
            {
                eolGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
        }
```

eolGrid is my datagrid, date equals DateTime.Today. I can change the default cell style back color of the entire grid using eolGrid.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor, but I cannot change individual row or cell colors.

Edit: I did read about a paint method that is called when a datagridview is created that can cause problems, would this be the case?

Comment: Please format your code to make it a bit easier to read.

Comment: what event does this code reside in..? is it in the `OnDataBound` Event..? also have you used the Debugger @David to step through the code..? google how to use `datagridviewcellcellstyle` for starters.. also here is a previous link that you can use for examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105718/datagridview-changing-cell-background-color

Comment: Your code as such looks ok. I suggest to pull out the dateonce before all those comparisons; this will also make it easier to debug..: `DateTime dateVal = Convert.ToDateTime(eolGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value;` or `DateTime dateVal = (DateTime)(DGV.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);`

Comment: It is not residing in any event, it is in the main public myForm().I have stepped through the code and the compiler runs through it but when the form comes up, the original colors are unchanged. @MethodMan

Comment: Thank you @Taw, the code looks cleaner now, however it still doesn't work :/

Comment: What does the debugger say??

Comment: The code compiles fine, control flows exactly as it should, yet the colors remain unchanged when the form appears.  No messages from the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everyone, I found that using the event handler: "RowPostPaint" repaints the each individual row after the datagridview has already been painted. This is my code if anyone's interested:

```
    private void eolGrid_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowNum = e.RowIndex;
        DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();

        DateTime dateval = Convert.ToDateTime(eolGrid.Rows[rowNum].Cells[3].Value);

        if ((dateval - date).TotalDays <= 0)
            style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        else if ((dateval - date).TotalDays <= 14)
            style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else
            style.ForeColor = Color.Black;

        eolGrid.Rows[rowNum].Cells[3].Style = style;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found this answered by Ehsan [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728009/changing-datagridview-cell-color-dynamically)

```
dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[columnIndex].Style.BackColor = Color.Red
```

By what I saw on your code, you're changing the default color, this probably is changing the full datagrid and not only the cell you want.

changing the style inside the cell makes more sense, I never did it, but probably it work's for what you need

Comment: This will not code a whole row but only a single cell. The OP's original code is fine.

Comment: agree, but a simple foreach resolve it, something like
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(eolGrid.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value) <= date)
            foreach(Cell c in Cells)
                c.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;

Comment: Sure, but as I said, the original code is ok, so no need to write a loop. He should fix the real problem..

Comment: I tried this and the original colors are still being displayed, although the compiler does run through it

Comment: @NicollasBraga I have tried this but with no success