# I want to change the color of datagrid in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have this code, but it does't work:

```
 private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
 {
     dgv.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
 }
```

I want it to change back color, when click the cell.

Comment: Is it Windows Forms or WPF? Please post a [mcve]. "Doesn't work" is not a good description. Can you set a breakpoint, does the line even get called?

Comment: Sorry is Windows Forms :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataGridView changing cell background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105718/datagridview-changing-cell-background-color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine but you can't see it as long as the cell is also **selected**.

By simply deselecting the current or all cells you can see the new color  right away, i.e. before leaving the cell:

```
private void dgv_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  dgv.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
  //  deselect  either just the one you just selected..:
  dgv.CurrentCell.Selected = false;
  // ..or deselect all cells:
  dgv.ClearSelection();
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following statement. This should help you `dgv.CurrentCell.Style.SelectionBackColor=Color.Red`

Comment: This is taken directly from the op!?