# How to compare two datagridview without using datatable/dataset

Tags: c#, datagridview, compare

I read in two files in two different datagridviews and I don't use any DataTable or DataSet. I need to compare both datagridviews/both files and need to mark the differences in the cells in a red color.

I already compare both files and show the differences in a message box, but it is not clear to notice them, so I wanted to show the differences in the datagridview by marking the cells red.

```
private void compareDatagridviews()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        var row1 = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells;
        var row2 = dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells;

        for (int j = 0; j < row1.Count; j++)
        {
            if (!row1[j].ToString().Equals(row2[j].ToString()))
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing happens when I press the button which calls the function above.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105718/datagridview-changing-cell-background-color Otherwise use the debugger to narrow down the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with this

```
    private void compareDatagridviews()
    {
        DataTable src1 = GetDataTableFromDGV(dataGridView1);
        DataTable src2 = GetDataTableFromDGV(dataGridView2);

        for (int i = 0; i < src1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var row1 = src1.Rows[i].ItemArray;
            var row2 = src2.Rows[i].ItemArray;

            for (int j = 0; j < row1.Length; j++)
            {
                if (!row1[j].ToString().Equals(row2[j].ToString()))
                {
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the GetDataTableFromDGV function that I use:

```
       private DataTable GetDataTableFromDGV(DataGridView dgv)
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dgv.Columns)
        {
            if (column.Visible)
            {
                // You could potentially name the column based on the DGV column name (beware of dupes)
                // or assign a type based on the data type of the data bound to this DGV column.
                dt.Columns.Add();
            }
        }

        object[] cellValues = new object[dgv.Columns.Count];
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                cellValues[i] = row.Cells[i].Value;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(cellValues);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but you have to specify that you want the value:

```
if (!row1[j].Value.ToString().Equals(row2[j].Value.ToString())) ...
```

Comment: Thank you, that didn't worked, because I get the System.NullReferenceException. Anyways I could solve the problem by myself.