# How to set style in for a column in DataGridView at design time

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

There's a question about [changing cell background color in a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16105718/1366033) programatically

But is there any way to set the background color for a particular column  *using the WinForms Designer*?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click the DataGridView and select Edit Columns

   [image: Edit Columns]
2. Select the DefaultCellStyle Property and click on the Style Wizard

   [image: DefaultCellStyle]
3. In the CellStyle Builder window, you can set whatever properties you'd like, including `BackColor`

   [image: CellStyle Builder]

What this will do is set the property inside of the *form.designer.cs* file during `InitializeComponent()`

```cs
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    /// ...
    this.ShadedColumn.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Silver;
    /// ...
}
```

<sup>* where *`this.ShadedColumn`* is the name of the `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` control you added</sup>

Any code in `InitializeComponent` will execute during the designer view, and technically you *can* update most styles directly here, but it's advised to use the GUI form builder to make any changes against this file

**Further Reading**: [Set Default Cell Styles and Data Formats for the Windows Forms DataGridView Control Using the Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/default-cell-styles-datagridview)