# How to set background color of each cell of each column of a selected row in DataGridView WinForms?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn, datagridviewcellstyle

What I have tried,
The below line of code changes a complete column background color.

```
dataGridView.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```

But, I want to work the same for only a selected row.
For example, I have 4 columns in datagridview, and when I select the row. Selected rows should have a different background color for every column.

This is how am getting a selected row.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow dvr in dataGridView.SelectedRows)
                {
                   dvr.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                  
                }
```

I am able to get the cell value of the selected row but I can't access the cell value back color property.

Any idea how I can do this. Please help

Comment: Okay i have got my question's solution and that is 
dvr.Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
from Olivier Rogier's link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105718/

Thank you all for your guides . How do i accept your solution now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataGridView changing cell background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105718/datagridview-changing-cell-background-color)