# How to know when date format is wrong in datagridview C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview

**What I am trying to Do:**
I have excel data (containing dates) which I am importing into datagridview. I want to mark those datagridview cells red which are not as per format (dd-MMM-YYYY).

**The problem:**
If you look at my if condition, I am trying to get dateformat but its for whole column. How to specify dateformat for Cell? I know it must be pretty straight forward but I am unable to crack it.
Here is my code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 2; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 5; j++)
                {
                        if ( dataGridView1.Columns[j].DefaultCellStyle.Format != "dd-MMM-yyyy") //<<//
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Style.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                        }
                }
            }
```

**Question**
How to know when date format is wrong in datagridview cell

**Edit** My problem is more related to if condition. I am unable to tell computer that if value is not as per format in the 'Cell', change its background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataGridView changing cell background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105718/datagridview-changing-cell-background-color)

Comment: @selmiraljic No. I can't figure out date format. It does specify whole column but I want to apply it to specific cell

Comment: Have you tried combining `DateTime.TryParseExact` with the cell formatting event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting)

Comment: @flydog57 I did it without cell formatting event.

Comment: I think you might be using the format property incorrectly, the format property is used to apply a format to a cell so that you can not write anything in it unless it’s in that format and by default it is set to empty, so you can put anything in the cell. What you could do is check if the `Cell[j].Value` is in the format you expect it to be and based of of that set the `Cell[j].Style`. You can use something like this to check whether the cell value is in the correct format `var isCorrectFormat = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, ”dd-MMM-yyyy”, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found answer after trying so many solutions. Its using *DateTime.TryParseExact* and *CultureInfo*.

```
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
                string dateString = row.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                DateTime dateValue;

                if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "dd-MMM-yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
                {
                    row.Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                }               
        }
```

Comment: You could mark it as the answer. It could help the person who has the same issue.